# (GAE and django) template filter and time format display

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-templates, django-views

I defined this data structure:

```
class Foo(db.Model):
  created = db.DateTimeProperty(required = True)
```

In the view, I display the created time of the instance with this:

```
<p>{{ foo.created }}</p>
```

and it works perfectly:

```
2011-08-09 15:11:30.437000
```

then I set the time format with template filter:

```
<p>{{ foo.created|time:"P" }}</p>
```

and I got this:

```
3:11 p.m.
```

it's still perfect. But then I set the time format like this:

```
<p>{{ foo.created|time:"m/d H:i" }}</p>
```

Then I got error message:

> AttributeError: 'TimeFormat' object has no attribute 'm'

I tried the other time format code and I found that I can only display time with "minute" and "second".
Any time format related to "month" or "day" like "m", "M", "n", "N", and "F" would cause error message.

Can somebody tell me Why?

I want to display created time with month, day, minute and second.
And I don't want to do it this way:

```
{{ foo.created.date.month }}/{{ foo.created.date.day }} {{ foo.created.time.minute }}:{{ foo.created.time.second }}
```

I think it's wordy.

Thanks! and sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use the [date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#date) filter instead. From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#time)

```
The time filter will only accept parameters in the format string
that relate to the time  of day, not the date (for obvious reasons).
If you need to format a date, use the date filter.
```

m is month.

Comment: I think I ask a stupid question :P
Thank you very much! It really helps me!

Comment: So where is the datetime filter?

Comment: The filter is just date, also updated the answer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#date